# Disable console mess in CMUSphinx4

Tags: java, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I'm trying CMUSphinx but I'm having a hard time. I have included `core` and `data` jars to the project in Eclipse which I have downloaded from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~sphinx4)

I tried to do Live speech recognition as mentioned [in the tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4) but when I try to run it, the console is filled with some kind of errors like `The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word '....'` and many.

Code:

```
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;

public class Hello {       

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();


    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");

    configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");

    configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
    LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

    while(true)
    {
    System.out.println("Start speaking...");
    recognizer.startRecognition(true);
    SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
    System.out.println("result: "+result.getHypothesis());

    recognizer.stopRecognition();
    }

}
}
```

Console:

```
23:15:07.552 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: *+NSN+
23:15:07.556 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: *+SPN+
23:15:07.556 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AA
23:15:07.556 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AE
23:15:07.556 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AH
23:15:07.556 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AO
...
...     /* Similar to above messages */
...
...
23:15:08.447 INFO autoCepstrum         Cepstrum component auto-configured as follows: autoCepstrum {MelFrequencyFilterBank, Denoise, DiscreteCosineTransform2, Lifter}
2016-02-22 23:15:08.649 java[68475:2340128] 23:15:08.649 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
Start speaking... /* My Output */
23:15:08.653 INFO dictionary           Loading dictionary from: jar:file:/Users/sriharish/Java/sphinx4-data-5prealpha-20151218.160017-5.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
23:15:08.786 INFO dictionary           Loading filler dictionary from: jar:file:/Users/sriharish/Java/sphinx4-data-5prealpha-20151218.160017-5.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us/noisedict
23:15:08.786 INFO acousticModelLoader  Loading tied-state acoustic model from: jar:file:/Users/sriharish/Java/sphinx4-data-5prealpha-20151218.160017-5.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us
23:15:08.787 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool means Entries: 16128
23:15:08.787 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool variances Entries: 16128
23:15:08.787 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool transition_matrices Entries: 42
23:15:08.787 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool senones Entries: 5126
23:15:08.787 INFO acousticModelLoader  Gaussian weights: mixture_weights. Entries: 15378
23:15:08.787 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool senones Entries: 5126
23:15:08.787 INFO acousticModelLoader  Context Independent Unit Entries: 42
23:15:08.788 INFO acousticModelLoader  HMM Manager: 137095 hmms
23:15:08.788 INFO acousticModel        CompositeSenoneSequences: 0
23:15:08.789 INFO trieNgramModel       Loading n-gram language model from: jar:file:/Users/sriharish/Java/sphinx4-data-5prealpha-20151218.160017-5.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin
23:15:09.821 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word '3-d'
23:15:09.821 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word '3-d'
23:15:09.830 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'adjustors'
23:15:09.830 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'adjustors'
...
...    /* Similar to above messages */
...

23:15:11.231 INFO lexTreeLinguist      Max CI Units 43
23:15:11.232 INFO lexTreeLinguist      Unit table size 79507
23:15:11.234 INFO speedTracker         # -----------------------------         Timers----------------------------------------
23:15:11.235 INFO speedTracker         # Name               Count   CurTime   MinTime   MaxTime   AvgTime   TotTime   
23:15:11.237 INFO speedTracker         Compile              1       1.1360s   1.1360s   1.1360s   1.1360s   1.1360s   
23:15:11.238 INFO speedTracker         Load Dictionary      1       0.1330s   0.1330s   0.1330s   0.1330s   0.1330s   
23:15:11.238 INFO speedTracker         Load AM              1       2.0880s   2.0880s   2.0880s   2.0880s   2.0880s   
23:15:11.238 INFO speedTracker         Load LM              1       1.3080s   1.3080s   1.3080s   1.3080s   1.3080s   
23:15:16.674 INFO speedTracker            This  Time Audio: 0.37s  Proc: 4.12s  Speed: 11.14 X real time
23:15:16.676 INFO speedTracker            Total Time Audio: 0.37s  Proc: 4.12s 11.14 X real time
23:15:16.676 INFO memoryTracker           Mem  Total: 738.00 Mb  Free: 378.28 Mb
23:15:16.676 INFO memoryTracker           Used: This: 359.72 Mb  Avg: 359.72 Mb  Max: 359.72 Mb
23:15:16.676 INFO trieNgramModel       LM Cache Size: 870 Hits: 153862 Misses: 870
result: none /* My Output */
```

I have downloaded recommended jars and included it in the project.So what is wrong with it? Did they failed to provide a dictionary? Can I add the missing `phonetic transcription`? If yes, provide a link please. And finally how can I disable all the console warnings etc and only have output that I provide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have the same problem where the only classes I'm using are StreamSpeechRecognizer and Configuration. After looking through the sphinx source for ConfigurationManagerUtils I've managed to get the follow code in my own classes to disable all console logging from edu.cmu.sphinx packages. Place this code before instantiating the recognizer.

```
  Logger cmRootLogger = Logger.getLogger("default.config");
  cmRootLogger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
  String conFile = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file");
  if (conFile == null) {
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "ignoreAllSphinx4LoggingOutput");
  }
```

Hardly elegant but it works for me, unless someone has a cleaner approach for disabling logging at **runtime** through the sphinx configuration/context classes.

As with any third party packages I need to consume in my own project, I have a valid reason for doing this directly in code because 1/ I don't care to expose any third party logging and 2/ I don't wish to ship customised logging configuration files for third party code.

Comment: Wow, thankx bro. It solved my issue.