# Disable sphinx4 log messages

Tags: java, sphinx4

I'm trying CMUSphinx4 tutorials and I'm getting some weird `Info unitManager` ,`INFO acousticModelLoader` etc related stuff in the console when I try to run. I came across same questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560969/disable-console-mess-in-cmusphinx4) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/sphinx4/thread/b18b7f93/).

[Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/sphinx4/thread/b18b7f93/) they suggested to change `value="INFO"` to `value="WARNING"` or `value="OFF"`.But how can I change the `default.config.xml` present inside jar file? I thought of extracting the .jar file , editing and repacking it but it doesn't work based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688870/adding-new-words-in-sphinx-4-helloworld-demo?rq=1).

I downloaded jar files from repository and included in the eclipse.So, how can I add/change `config.xml` file?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable console mess in CMUSphinx4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560969/disable-console-mess-in-cmusphinx4)

Answer (score -1):

Download sphinx4 sources, change default.config.xml and build a new jar. It'll be the right way.

Or, of course, you can always open Jar file as a simple archive and try to patch it inside.