# Disable INFO messages from Sphinx4

Tags: logging, console, sphinx4, info

How do I disable red INFO messages when running stream or live recognizer? I am using Configuration, not ConfigurationManager no I can't modify default.config.xml

Comment: Whay have you tried?

Comment: I researched but couldn't try anything because it involves changing the default.config.xml which is bundled with the Jar. There's no way to set the xml with a method either. I checked all the constructor and methods of relvent classes

Comment: Do you have access to the afore mentioned Jar file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable console mess in CMUSphinx4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560969/disable-console-mess-in-cmusphinx4)

Comment: @EthanStrider I am using Maven for the dependency. Technically I could download the src and use from there instead. I was wondering if there's a cleaner way. They must have some kind of method to disable it?

Comment: Thank you guys anyway. I've posted an answer

Answer (score 6):

Ok so the cleanest way I've found is if you're using maven then in the resources folder create edu/cmu/sphinx/api folders and inside api put the default.config.xml from [here](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-core/src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/api/default.config.xml). Then edit this xml file and change the logLevel property value to OFF. That should remove the info messages from console. Good luck!

Comment: Works for me! Thank you